# For Divisors, do we use order of the point or multiplicity of the point?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

This is from the Book Mathematical Cryptography by Silverman, Pipher etc.

From the book where they describe Rational Functions & their Divisors on Elliptic Curves

> **5.8.2** Rational functions and divisors on elliptic curves
> We keep track of the zeros and poles of $f(X)$ and their **multiplicities** by defining the divisor of $f(X)$ to be the formal sum

> $div(f(X)) = b_1[{\alpha}_1] + b_2[{\alpha}_2] + ... + b_r[{\alpha}_r] - d_1[{\beta}_1] - d_2[{\beta}_2] - ... - d_r[{\beta}_r]$ **--- (A)**

Here the book describes ${\alpha}_1$, ${\alpha}_2$ etc as the zeroes, $b_1$, $b_2$ etc as their **multiplicities** & similarly for the poles ${\beta}_1$ etc.

Few pages ahead in the book, where it describes a Weil Pairing with an example, we see this

$e_m(P, Q)$ is described as the Weil Pairing map for all $P, Q \in E(m)$ for $m$-torsion points on Elliptic Curve $E$.
So $e_2$ will be the map for the 2-torsion points.

Now the example

> *Example* 5.40. We are going to compute $e_2$ directly from the definition. Let $E$ be given by the equation $Y^2 = X^3 + Ax + B = (X − {\alpha}_1)(X − {\alpha}_2)(X − {\alpha}_3)$.
> Note that ${\alpha}_1 + {\alpha}_2 + {\alpha}_3 = 0$, since the left-hand side has no $X^2$ term. The points $P1 = ({\alpha}_1, 0), P2 = ({\alpha}_2, 0), P3 = ({\alpha}_3, 0)$, are points of **order 2**, and as noted earlier,

> $div(X − {\alpha}_i) = 2[P_i] − 2[\mathcal O]$ **--- (B)**

---

In **(A)**, the book says that in the term $b_r[{\alpha}_r]$, $b_r$ is the multiplicity of the Point ${\alpha}_r$.

However, in **(B)** while writing down the divisor, he uses the order $2$ of the point $P$ instead of it's multiplicity. How can this be explained?

**UPDATE:**

The question has been partly answered but there are areas of confusion for me.

1. As per this - https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/55427/3941 they calculate that there are just **2 zeros** & hence by Bazout's, hence the divisor is $2[P] - 2[\mathcal O]$. Whereas in the answer below, the same result is arrived at in a very different way - $(2[P_i]+[\mathcal{O}])-(3[\mathcal{O}])=2[P_i]-2[\mathcal{O}]$
2. Is $[0:1:0]$ a zero? $f$ evaluates to $\frac {0 -{a_i}0}{0}$ at $[0:1:0]$ - it's a divide by zero. So is it really a zero? It works only if we calculate zeros of numerator separately without including the denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In (B), the term "order" is referring to the order of the point in the group law on the elliptic curve. It is not so simple as "point of order $n$" implies "that point appears in some divisor with multiplicity $n$" - there is actual math happening there.

To calculate the divisor of $f=X-a_i$, we first write the rational function $f$ on the affine open subset $D(Z)\cap E$ of $E$ as a ratio of homogeneous polynomials of the same degree, which will let us more easily determine the behavior of our function away from $D(Z)\cap E$. To do this, we homogenize with respect to $Z$ and then divide by $Z$ to the degree of the resulting polynomial. Here, homogenizing $f$ with respect to $Z$ gives $X-a_iZ$, and then we divide by $Z$ to obtain $f=\frac{X-a_iZ}{Z}$. Now we determine the divisor of $f$ by counting with multiplicity the intersections of $V(X-a_iZ)$ and $V(Z)$ with $E$ and taking their difference.

$V(X-a_iZ)$ meets $E$ at $[a_i:0:1]$ and $[0:1:0]$. From the construction of the group law on elliptic curves using lines, a point $P$ of order two has a vertical tangent which meets the curve with multiplicity two at $P$. Therefore $V(X-a_iZ)$ meets $E$ at $[a_i:0:1]$ with multiplicity two and therefore the divisor $V(X-a_iZ)\cap E$ is $2[P_i]+[\mathcal{O}]$. $V(Z)$ meets $E$ at $[0:1:0]$, so the divisor of $V(Z)\cap E$ is $3[\mathcal{O}]$. Subtracting the two gives $div(f) = 2[P_i]-2[\mathcal{O}]$.

---

Addressing the update:

1. Yes, there are two zeroes of $f$: $P_i$ twice. This is exactly what the above calculation shows. (I would push back a little on the phrasing that "the same result is arrived at in a very different way" - the linked answer from the cryptography site does not explain their method. In fact, by writing $X-a_i$ as $\frac{X-a_iZ}{Z}$, there is a suggestion that they might be doing it the same way I am.)
2. This is like asking "to what order does the function $\frac{x^n}{x^m}$ on $\Bbb R$ vanish at zero?" Well, $x^n$ vanishes to order $n$, and $x^m$ vanishes to order $m$, so the total order of vanishing is $x^{n-m}$. To be specific, the local ring of every point on the curve $E$ is a valuation ring, so we can ask what the valuation is of $f$ in the local ring at $\mathcal{O}$. Valuations add over multiplication, so it really does work exactly the same as the example. The calculation here is that first we dehomogenize the numerator and denominator with respect to $Y$, so $f$ can be written as $\frac{(X-a_iZ)/Y}{Z/Y}$. Now both the numerator and denominator are functions defined on the affine open neighborhood $D(Y)\cap E$ of $\mathcal{O}$, so we can compute their valuations, which are exactly equal to the intersection multiplicities of numerator and denominator with $E$ at $\mathcal{O}$. So the numerator has valuation $1$ and the denominator has valuation $3$, leading to a total valuation of $-2$. So $f$ has a pole of order $2$ at $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: I don't understand the "subtract the Intersections with multiplicity of $Z$" - why are you doing this? And how do you calculate the Intersections with multiplicity of $Z$?

Comment: The divisor associated to a rational function is the divisor of zeroes minus the divisor of poles. For an elliptic curve embedded by a Weierstrass equation, there is only one point on the line $Z=0$, so the intersection multiplicity there must be 3 by Bezout.

Comment: I understand that number of zeros is number of poles - I am confused about how you got from $X-{a_i}Z$ to $\frac {X-{a_i}Z}{Z}$ & where the $+[\mathcal O]$ comes from? From your answer, I can understand where the $2[P_i]$ comes from - it's because $P$ is the tangential intersection - so the multiplicity of $P$ is 2. But where does the $+[\mathcal O]$ come from. Once I get that, then the number of poles will be obvious.

Comment: The function $X-a_i$ is written in affine coordinates on $D(Z)$, so to write it as a ratio of homogeneous polynomials of equal degrees, we need to homogenize and then divide by an appropriate power of $Z$. Homogenization looks like turning $a_i$ in to $a_iZ$, and then we divide by $Z$ since our numerator is of degree 1. The $+\mathcal{O}$ comes from the fact that the line $V(X-a_iZ)$ intersects our elliptic curve in projective space at $\mathcal{O}$: plugging $[0:1:0]$ in to $X-a_iZ$ gives zero. The multiplicity is one because this line is not the tangent line at $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: Sorry, if I am being dumb here, but from what I have read, if we homogenize ${x^2}y - y +4$, it becomes ${x^2}y -y{z^2} + 4{z^3}$, it's not expressed as a ratio & we don't add a denominator. Why when homogenizing $X-{a_i}$, we don't stop at $X-{a_i}Z$, but also add a denominator (1) & homogenize that also?

Comment: Our goal isn't just to homogenize our function - we want to write our function as a ratio of homogeneous polynomials so that we can calculate the poles and zeroes by looking at the numerator and denominator. Our function $x-a_i$ is already an element of $k(E)$, the fraction field of our elliptic curve, but it's not immediately clear how it behaves off the affine patch where it's defined. Writing it as a restriction of a ratio of homogeneous polynomials makes it easier to understand it's behavior globally.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one more thing, I am not sure if $[0:1:0]$ is a zero, because $f$ evaluates to $\frac {0 -{a_i}0}{0}$ at $[0:1:0]$ - it's divided by 0 & hence not a zero - so there is just this zero $[{a_i}:0:1]$ (of multiplicity 2) & by Bezout's there will 2 poles & hence the div = $2[P] - 2[\mathcal O]$ - this seems to gel with another answer I found also - https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/55427/3941

Comment: The point $[0:1:0]$ is a zero of the *numerator* of order one and a zero of the *denominator* of order 3, which gives a total multiplicity of $-2$, corresponding to the coefficient of $-2$ on $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: @user93353 I've made an edit addressing your updated questions.

Comment: Thank you very much